# Always see the first tab

Tags: angular, angular-material, tabs

I have a mat-tabs-group which contains many tabs like this [image: image of tabs]

And I want the tab named "show always" to always be visible.
And that when I browse my horizontal list, that the first tab is always static like the left arrow.

example :
[image: image of problem]
Here, I need to see the first tab next to tab 4.

I tried a few solutions, but never found them.

Do you have any leads? thank you

Comment: Please provide code in stackblitz